# Is it known if 'most' first order statements are decidable or undecidable?

Tags: first-order-logic

If we enumerate the statements we can prove as decidable with proof or negation and enumerate the statements we can prove as undecidable, with satisfiability, forcing, or an incompleteness proof, is it known if the ratio of provably decidable statements to provably undecidable statements goes to zero or infinity? Or does the unknowable number of unprovably undecidable statements (from Church's theorem I believe there must be statements that are unprovably undecidable) make this question unanswerable?

My intuition suggests that the larger the quantifier rank, the more likely it is to be undecidable.

Comment: Given one provably undecidable statement you can construct at least as many provably undecidable statements as there are provably decidable statements, by use of "AND".

Comment: @Henry: Let's be constructive here. We can assume some reasonable enumeration of all well-formed statements $-$ say, one which enumerates the statements in order of increasing length.